# If Emma is that powerful, why does she still need to drive her yellow VW Bug?

Tags: magic, once-upon-a-time

Mr. Gold, the formerly Evil Queen, the ambiguously evil Snow Queen, and the green-coloured-witch of Oz simply needed the wave of an arm to be teleported to wherever vicinity they so wish.

And now that we are to discover that Emma is part of a trinity whose power eclipses them all, and yet Emma needs to go places with a VW Bug still?

Please help me make sense of the situation.

Comment: Maybe she just enjoys driving.

Comment: Regina didn't magic herself over to Robin, either, in this last episode

Comment: Where do you get the impression that Emma NEEDS her bug to go places?? The fact she uses it, doesn't necessarily mean she has to. From what we know the town isn't that big - she could probably walk (which on a side note makes me wonder where they get their gas from, when practically noone can enter or leave...?), but maybe she keeps "Sherrif stuff" in the bug??

Comment: You have not lived in Maine. Or Iowa. A "small" town = small in population. It may be large in area. It could miles and miles of corn fields, or tree farms. For example, Allagash ME = 131 sq miles with only 239 persons !!! According to the story, Storybrook ME has the area the size of kingdom.

Comment: +izkata, Regina did not magic herself over to Robin, because according to OUAT principles "love is the strongest magic".

Comment: IF +numaroth converts the comment to an answer I would vote it up.

Comment: Do we ever see her putting gas in her car? Leaving it at the mechanic's for a brake job? It's possible she is using magic to get around, she's just not showing off. Or she isn't aware she's using it on her car - she just turns the key and goes, and just never thinks about gas and maintenance.

Answer (score 3):

I can think of three possible reasons why Emma, as well as other characters like Regina and Rumple, do not always utilize teleportation as a means of travel. I have not seen seasons 1 and 2, but I am basing my answers off of magical tropes from other series as well as what I have seen and can remember from seasons 3 and 4.

## 1. Efficiency/Energy Requirement

All magic comes with a price in this universe. I am unsure if magic is explicitly stated to use the caster's energy in Once Upon a Time, but it's not out of the question. It may be more efficient to walk or drive short distances than to magic yourself there, just as it is more efficient to drive from Washington, DC to Baltimore than it is to take a commercial flight. This makes more sense when you consider the radius of any teleportation spell is limited to Storybrook's town line (since magic doesn't exist in the mundane world outside of the town). Additionally, there may be a cost to using teleportation too much (such as an increased probability of disease or cancer) that prevents characters like Regina or Mr. Gold from abusing its convenience

## 2. Stealth

Evil characters like Cora and the Snow Queen may be able to sense magic, either innately or through some early-warning alarm spell. It's quite possible the other characters in the show do not use their magic during key parts to prevent detection (such as Emma in the two-hour episode that aired a few weeks back).

## 3. Skill

The most likely explanation for why Emma specifically cannot use magic to travel; teleportation is an intermediate or advanced-level technique, a mark of a master mage. Emma has only recently started to master her magic - it was only in the second half of last season that she received her first lesson. To be able to dematerialize yourself, then reappear in a precise spot, without materializing your kidney inside a tree branch, your kneecaps inside a hill, or your head ten feet from the ground or something equally life-threatening, must be incredibly difficult. Plus, consider all of the magic users who have been shown to have teleported in seasons 3 and 4. Regina - master magic user, daughter of Cora, trained by the Dark One. Zelena - master magic user, daughter of Cora, trained by the Dark One. Rumpelstiltskin - the Dark One, teacher of the previous two and of Cora (I think). Snow Queen - master user of magic, capable of casting the spell of Shattered Sight which is powerful enough to circumvent one of the rules of magic (you can't change a person's heart. ). The simplest explanation for why Emma does not zip around Storybrook in clouds of smoke is that she is simply not capable of it.

Comment: Are you writing a Boeing's or Intel's SOP (standard operating procedure) on OUAT for their QA dept?

Comment: @BlessedGeek I...I don't know what either of those are. I just copied how I've seen other people write answers on Stack Exchange.

Comment: When Henry first showed up at Emma's door, she refused to believe in magic. She's been on a slow journey of discovery of who and what she is. Still likely in denial and disbelief, despite intentionally using her magic to save the day more than once. That and a lack of confidence and trust in her magical abilities, and control of them would keep her from using magic for anything less than the most exceptional of circumstances.